# How can I retrieve large number of documents from Mongo datastore using Morphia?

Tags: java, mongodb, java-8, morphia

I am using following code to iterate through a database's documents.

```
public void readDataStore() throws IOException {
        Query query = document_datastore.find(DocumentPojo.class);
        List<DocumentPojo> documentPojos = query.asList();

        documentPojos.forEach(obj -> {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(obj.getDocid());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        );    
}
```

Currently the DB has not more than 100 documents but in future it can have ~100000 documents. I suspect then it may run into performance issues?

`DocumentPojo` is the class that I map the results to. I am using Java 8 and Morphia.

How should I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to load every document into memory? Usually you'll want to lookups to particular fields or run analytics via the aggregation framework and avoid loading full documents at all.

Comment: For analytics, I will be using Elasticsearch. The data that is indexed to Elasticsearch is not directly sent to Elasticsearch but rather is stored directly in MongoDB. Later, I take every document one by one and start pushing to Elasticsearch. Here I require to load complete document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`query.fetch()`](https://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.0/javadoc/org/mongodb/morphia/query/QueryResults.html#fetch()) to get the `MorphiaIterator` and then handle each document as you get it.  It won't pull them all in to memory at once allowing you to process your hundred thousand+ documents.

Answer (score 2):

One way of implementing @evanchooly's answer:

```
public void readDataStore() throws IOException {
    final Query query = document_datastore.find(DocumentPojo.class);

    query.fetch().forEach(obj -> {
        try {
            System.out.println(obj.getDocid());
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

}